# Indefinite article before "format"

Tags: indefinite-articles

I need to use this word with the following meaning:

> [the way in which data is stored or held to be worked on by a computer](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/format_1)

This particular dictionary doesn't say anything about whether this word is countable or not. The given example though contains an indefinite article:

> The images are stored in a digital format within the database.

So, it is supposed to be a countable noun. But when I reviewed some other examples I've discovered that putting an indefinite article along with the noun is not always the case:

> However, neither the raw nor the processed data were provided in digital format.
>
> No data were reported in digital format.

Could you please clarify the cases for me?

Comment: What is ***your*** sentence that you're confused about? (What's the context for your use of *format*?)

Comment: In my case it is the sentence:
> To be able to grab data from sources and store it in the special TSDB format...
I would go with "the" here because it implies the very known format (everybody should know it).

[There's a rule that states that a definite article should be used with an initialism if the one is the spelled out term](https://ontariotraining.net/grammar-tip-the-with-acronyms-and-initialisms/).

But again, I've found out an opposite example where an indefinite article resides:
> The trial version allows you to save the image in a special TPI format.

Comment: The use of an adjective in front of a noun often changes it from something uncountable to something countable. Also, both the definite and indefinite article can be used with something countable—although only the definite article can (in some constructions) be used with something that isn't countable. In both of your *special [adjective] format* sentences, the noun is countable—even though in the first sentence it seems to have a count of one.

Comment: @Jason Bassford 'although only the definite article can... be used with something that isn't countable.' This has been discussed before; it's not true. 'A good education is the right of every American child' uses non-count 'education' (you can't say 'three good educations ...'). / 'He spoke with a feeling I never thought him capable of.' but ** 'He spoke with 2 / 17 / several / many feelings I never thought him capable of.' //// However, here I'd say that 'in a digital format' must indicate that there are other possible formats.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *I received a good education in the UK, a poor education in the US, and a good education in Switzerland*. Those educations most certainly *are* countable. (I received two good educations and one bad one.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford Yes, but it's _specific usages_ that are count or non-count. You can't say "Two good educations are vital". // If you want an unarguable proof, "She smiled at us with an unusual friendliness."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I can say *two good educations are vital*. If, for example, I'm talking about different degrees or educations in different places or at different times. It's perfectly syntactic—as well as semantic in the right context. You just don't like it because it doesn't sound natural to you.

Comment: @Jason Bassford "If, for example, I'm talking about different degrees or educations in different places or at different times." But with 'A good education is vital', equivalent to 'it is vital to be well-educated', etic countness is _not_ in play. // And with 'She smiled at us with an unusual friendliness'? Countification has not even begun here, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use all three versions, as you choose: store it in TSDB format, store it in a TSDB format, or store it in the special TSDB format.  The subtle differences:

- in TSDB format: common geek speak.
- in a TSDB format: this suggests you are talking to a non-specialist.
- in the special TSDB format: this suggests that earlier in your communication with the person, you explained something about the TSDB format, and now you are referring back to that.

I would choose among these based on how well versed the other person is with this format.